# JS - how to get button text "end" position

Tags: javascript, gwt

I have a question concerning html button text position. As I can see it, there are ways to get left upper corner element positions but what about right upper corner. For example

I have button as:

```
<button style="text-align: left">Hello World</button>
```

...OK next I want to know what coordinates the inner text "Hello World" is ending. So is it possible to get it with js or what is the most optimal way?

Thanks

Comment: I can do it with jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/AYAPY/ But since jQuery is not tagged, I will not post it as an answer.

Comment: its great :) but what about pure js?

Comment: Here: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/AYAPY/2/ **Pure JavaScript**

Comment: So you mean that in this example the text "d" letter position {X,Y}{83,4} ?

Comment: @user592704 no, it means that directly after d, the top right corner is located at (83, 4). Do you want the location of "d"? If so, please adjust your question to reflect that.

Comment: Of course "d", because my question says "text end position"

Comment: @user592704 but that's a very ambiguous statement. If the | is the position that you want, do you want: `d|` or `|d`?

Comment: As my question title says, I want "end" text position so it is sure the coordinate X/Y where d letter "ends". So I guess it is the "d|"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

### Pure JavaScript

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/AYAPY/3/

```
//1. wrap with content <span>
var txt=document.querySelector("button").innerHTML;
document.querySelector("button").innerHTML="";
document.querySelector("button").appendChild(document.createElement("span"));
document.querySelector("button span").innerHTML=txt;

//2. Get the <span>'s coordinate
var end_y=document.querySelector("button span").offsetTop;
var end_x=document.querySelector("button span").offsetLeft+document.querySelector("button span").offsetWidth;

//3. Done!
alert(end_x+", "+end_y);
```

### With jQuery

Highly recommended.
http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/AYAPY/

---

[image]

> I put a little "`|`" thingy at the point, just to show you the coordinate returned is correct.

Comment: Please post your answer *here*, provide the *demo* elsewhere.

Comment: It is quite interesting. I am not pretty sure can this "var txt=document.querySelector("button").innerHTML;"
 be replaced with "var txt=element.innerHTML;" for example? I mean using "element" as function param.

Comment: @user592704 - If `element` is referring to the `DOM element`, then yes.

Answer (score 2):

Pass an element to getButtonCoords. It will return an object (let's call it `coords`). `coords.x` is the x coordinate and `coords.y` is the y coordinate.

```
/* from stackoverflow.com/questions/442404/dynamically-retrieve-html-element-x-y-position-with-javascript */
function getOffset( el ) {
    var _x = 0;
    var _y = 0;
    while( el && !isNaN( el.offsetLeft ) && !isNaN( el.offsetTop ) ) {
        _x += el.offsetLeft - el.scrollLeft;
        _y += el.offsetTop - el.scrollTop;
        el = el.offsetParent;
    }
    return { top: _y, left: _x };
}

function getButtonCoords(button) {
    /* wrap the text in a span element so we can get its coordinates */
    button.innerHTML = "<span id='button-text-" + button.id + "'>" + button.innerHTML + "</span>";

    /* get the span element */
    var button_span = document.getElementById('button-text-' + button.id);

    /* get the offset */
    var offset = getOffset(button_span);

    /* get the coordinates */
    var coords = { x: offset.left + button_span.offsetWidth, y: offset.top };

    /* return them */
    return coords;
}

/* get the button and pass it to the coordinate function */
var coords = getButtonCoords(document.getElementById('button-id'));
/* show the results */
alert(coords.x + ", " + coords.y);
```

Comment: @Derek: it doesn't look that similar to me. Yours uses a querySelector and appendChild, whereas mine prefers just using innerHTML. Mine returns an object, and uses a combination of the button's id and a suffix to generate an id, where you use query selectors. Mine is wrapped in a function, yours is not (trivial difference). Honestly, I don't see much alike, with the sole exception that we both use a `span` and `offset*` to detect the coordinates. `offset` isn't really a unique solution, and `span` is just a standard HTML tag which happens to do almost nothing except put the text in an element.

Comment: No no no, I don't mean all those fancy stuff you add in. I mean the *way of getting the coordinates*. I add in a `<span>` to determine the `x` and `y`, and you also add in a `<span>`. Mine uses `querySelector` to get the element, and you also use similar method to get the element.

Comment: I will concede the `<span>` point: our codes do look similar in that respect, but I still did not "steal" it from you. `<span>` is not a unique concept or idea, it has been known for quite some time that `<span>` provides an easy way to reference certain parts of text (cf: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp "manipulate with ... JavaScript" "add a hook to a part of a text" "no visual change"). As for `querySelector`, I do not believe that constitutes as similar. The method of creating a new id for the `span` element doesn't seem similar to querySelector or the syntax for querySelector.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you want. Do you want me to delete my post? Do you want attribution? Do you want your post to be accepted as the "correct answer"? I didn't steal your code. Getting the location of the element in this way is not unique, it's basic logic. The top-right coordinate of any rectangle is its (x + width, y). You could figure that out by just drawing a picture. I still dispute that I have "almost the same thing". There are very few correct ways to do something. Searching "javascript find element coordinates" would produce practically the same code when parent == body.

Comment: I was just saying... sorry if you think I was being mean.

Comment: @Derek: I updated it with the function I originally used (removed the assumption that element.parent == body). This should clear up any confusion about the origin of my code. I also upvoted your post, because you did post a version of the correct code before me. No hard feelings.